# Concurrent Execution Exception while starting Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

Tomcat server is not starting in eclipse which was working fine before but now its showing the following exception.

In this application using the jersey to consume the API
Any Jar is missing?

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig

How to solve this issue?

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PhonePayService]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PhonePayService]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/server/impl/application/DeferredResourceConfig
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1623)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    ... 18 more

Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more

Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 11 more

Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 24, 2017 3:34:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: Maybe you should show your dependencies, such as Pom file or gradle file.

Comment: In this one i am not using any Pom file gradle file.

Comment: Please write what jersey jars you are using and jersey config. It seems that you are trying to load jersey 1 class

Comment: yes,i was trying to load jersey 1 later changed to version 2 then it's working fine.